# How to serve content that can't be served via nginx or apache by Django?

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I need to serve some content that should be preprocessed before getting served. There are huge volume of files (500,000 files with sizes around 1GB for example.) My server is written in Django. I can do the preprocess in python (a Django view for example) but I can't do it in Nginx or other static file servers. Is there anyway to implement a Django view that serves these files efficiently with random access? Is there any modules for this purpose? What should I take care of to implement it?

P.S. The files are not saved anywhere, there are around 2000 files and all other files can get generated by these 2000 files in the python code (Django view). I don't wanna buy that much hard disk to preprocess and store all 500,000 final files.

Comment: For the preprocessing, you could use RQ workers and trigger / monitor the jobs with django-rq, or if more complex, use Celery, but RQ can already achieve a lot and is really easier to use.

Comment: What kind of content are these "final files" holding? We really need more info to be able to help.

Comment: @Apero as I said in the question I don't want to preprocess files unless when user asks for it and I don't want to store requested data, just serve them and that's it because storing them will lead to around 5,000TB. The final files are encrypted versions of the original files with different keys, but what they are shouldn't change anything.